# Unexpected delay in Verilog adder

Tags: verilog, fpga

I have written some Verilog code for an adder with 10 inputs.  After simulation I am getting the output with one extra clock delay.  Why am I getting this delay?

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module add_10(z0,z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6,z7,z8,z9,clk,reset,o);
input [7:0] z0,z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6,z7,z8,z9;
input clk,reset;
output reg[15:0] o;
always @ (posedge clk or negedge reset)
begin
    if (!reset)
        o=16'b0000;
    else
        o = z0+z1+z2+z3+z4+z5+z6+z7+z8+z9;
end
endmodule
```

After asserting the reset, I am getting the output after one clock. But according to the code I wrote, it should come at the next posedge clk when `reset=1`.

[image]

Comment: I don't know the timing of your clock, but you are essentially stringing 10 8-bit adders in series. That will cause some delay. If you need precise timing, it would be better to store the result of the addition in a register and clock it out on the next cycle.

Comment: In the testbench i am declaring the generation of reset and after using non-blocking assignments also i am unable to get the correct output. So in what way i need to change my program to get the output as i discussed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's working as it should to me.

I think you're misunderstanding how the `reset` signal is meant to be used.  The `reset` signal should be kept high at all times. When it goes low, the output will be cleared immediately (it changes on the negative edge).  When it goes high, the `output` will take on the sum of the inputs on the next clock cycle.

If you wanted to update on the positive edge of the `reset` signal, use the positive edge...

```
always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
...
```

Just beware that doing so will likely affect your minimum cycle times.

Comment: Forgive me if I use the wrong terminology in my explanation, it's been a while since I've last used Verilog and I've forgotten a lot of the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably working as expected, but it may not be. The issue is (a) that you're not showing how reset is generated, and (b) you're using blocking assignments (which you shouldn't be; use `<=`), so you may have a race elsewhere, in your reset generation.

Show the code that generates reset. If there are no race conditions, then your waveform is correct; edge A clears reset, but this isn't seen by your adder, which thinks that reset is still asserted; the adder sees it de-asserted on the *next* clock edge, so produces a result.

Comment: In the testbench i am declaring the generation of reset and after using non-blocking assignments also i am unable to get the correct output. So in what way i need to change my program to get the output as i discussed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change the timing of reset with respect to clk in your testbench. The way you have it, reset and clk change simultaneously. I believe the simulator enters your always block as a result of posedge clk, while the value of reset is still 0, and therefore assigns 0 to your output.

I would shift the reset to the left or to the right of the posedge of the clock. That should give you the effect you are looking for.